# Laravel add dynamic parameter before route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a route like

```
http://localhost.fbleads.com/{dynamic-value}/auth/facebook-login
```

It give me error that `route not found`. Any solution for this

Comment: Please provide more code. What you have done so far?

Comment: if you have url like that you should define route like this:
```route::get('/{dynamic-value}/auth/facebook-login','samplecontroller@index');```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your routes you could maybe have something like:

```
Route::get('{dynamic-value}/auth/facebook-login', [
    'as' => 'auth.login',
    'uses' => 'AuthController@login'
]);
```

the `{dynamic_value}` can be anything and be accessible as parameter in your controller method

Comment: I'm glad it works for you! Please accept the answer so other people can relate to it :)